# How to show a polynomial $f(x,y)$ over an alg closed field cannot have a zero at exactly one point?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Let $f \in k[x,y]$ be a given polynomial.

Could anyone explain how to show that
if $f(x,y) \neq0$ for all $(x,y) \in (k\times k)\setminus\{(0,0)\}$,
then $f$ is constant?

Comment: Hint: consider $f$ as a polynomial in $y$ with coefficients in $k[x]$. By plugging in values $x_0 \in k$ for $x$, you can reduce to the case of the one-variable polynomial $f(x_0,y)$.

Comment: @dxiv My mistake, I will fix the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Lemma**. Let $g\in k[x]$.
Assume $g(x_0)\ne0$ for all $x_0\in k$.
Then $g$ is constant.

*Proof.*
If $g$ is not constant, then $g$ has a root $x_0$, i.e., $g(x_0)=0$, since $k$ is algebraically closed.
This shows the lemma.

Now consider the condition in question.
Let $f\in k[x,y]$ with nonzero values on $k^{2}\setminus\{0\}$.

**Claim.** The values $f(x_0,y_0)$ for $x_0,y_0\in k\setminus\{0\}$ are all the same.

*Proof.* Let $x_0,y_0\in k\setminus\{0\}$.
Since the polynomial $g(y)=f(x_0,y)$ in $y$ is constant by assumption and by Lemma, we have $f(x_0,y_0)=f(x_0,1)$.
Similarly since $f(x,1)$ is constant, we see that $f(x_0,1)=f(1,1)$.
This shows the claim.

Let $a$ be the value $f(1,1)$ as in Claim.
Let  $g(x,y)=f(x,y)-a\in k[x,y]$.
It suffices to show $g=0$.
For any $x_0\in k\setminus\{0\}$ the polynomial $g(x_0,y)$ is constantly $0$ by Claim (and by Lemma).
Thus $g$ is in the ideal $(x-x_0)$ in $k[x,y]$.
Since there are infinitely many $x_0\in k\setminus\{0\}$, it follows that $g=0$.

Comment: Why is $g(y)$ constant?

Comment: @nonuser If $g$ is nonconstant, then it has a root $\beta$ by the fundamental theorem of algebra. But then $f(x_0, \beta) = 0$ and $(x_0,\beta) \neq (0,0)$ (since in particular $x_0 \neq 0$), contrary to the assumption.

Comment: @nonuser Thank you. I added that.